Fisher Information eigenvector regularity
I have a question regarding the regularity of the Fisher Information Matrix spectrum. Let us assume to have a statistical model $p_\theta$ with $\theta\in\Theta\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ compact such that $\theta\mapsto p_{\theta}$ is C^{1,1}. Then it holds that $\theta \mapsto F(\theta)$ is a Lipschitz matrix-valued function. Then, it holds that $\theta \mapsto \lambda_i(\theta)$ is a Lipschitz function where $\lambda_i(\theta)$ denotes the i-th eigenvalues of $F(\theta)$. I know that in general is not true that $\theta \mapsto u_{i}(\theta)$ is Lipschitz where $u_{i}(\theta)$ is the i-th eigenvalues of $F(\theta)$, and it generally happens when you have eigenvalues with multiplicity strictly larger that 1. Can we say that the $\mathcal{L}(A) = 0$ where $$A:= \{\theta\in\Theta: \, \exists \lambda_i(\theta) \,s.t.\, mult(\lambda_i(\theta))>1\}$$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Theta$. Intuitively, I would say that it is true since the eigenvalues are the roots of some polynomial, but I have no clue on how to prove it.
Thanks in advance!
